# HTML entities not showing up correctly

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed

The body of [this post](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/1025/28) contains a bunch of `&#x266d;` entities in the source, which <s>are</s> **were** showing up as plain text in the rendered post as well instead of the flat symbols (♭).  Oddly enough the preview below the post when editing showed the symbols properly.

Now that I've edited the post, the symbols are rendered normally.

What happened here?  Are we going to need to check other posts for this and edit them as well?

Comment: @BenAlpert Sorry, my edit on that post (and this one) seems to have interfered with your testing :P. I was alerted to the issue by a flag and saw it myself; it went away after I edited the post. At this point I'm wondering if it was a hiccup in the bit of the SE code that caches the rendered post or if it's a deeper issue.

Comment: Did you notice if the [revisions](http://music.stackexchange.com/posts/1025/revisions) also exhibited the incorrect behavior?

Comment: @JarrodDixon Nope, sorry.  I would've checked that had I expected my edit to fix things ... but I didn't expect that :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a [bug in a markdown regex](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109262/unicode-entities-are-shown-in-preview-but-not-in-the-post/109279#109279), which was actually fixed around the same time that post was last edited (before your recent edit). So that post was still rendered with the buggy engine; would it have been edited a day later (after the fix was deployed), it would have looked correct.

The revision list always uses the *current* version of the Markdown engine, that's why it doesn't show the issue anymore.